# How to run a Python Script from Deno?

Tags: python, typescript, deno

I have a python script with the following code:

```
print("Hello Deno")
```

I want to run this python script (test.py) from test.ts using Deno. This is the code in test.ts so far:

```
const cmd = Deno.run({cmd: ["python3", "test.py"]});
```

How can I get the output, of the python script in Deno?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To execute a python script from Deno you need to use [`Deno.Command`](https://deno.land/api?s=Deno.Command)

```
const command = new Deno.Command('python3', {
  args: [ "test.py" ],
});
const { code, stdout, stderr } = await command.output();
console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(stdout));
console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(stderr));
```

---

**Old answer:** `Deno.run` is now deprecated in favor of `Deno.Command`

`Deno.run` returns an instance of [`Deno.Process`](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#Deno.Process). In order to get the output use `.output()`. Don't forget to pass `stdout/stderr` options if you want to read the contents.

```
// --allow-run
const cmd = Deno.run({
  cmd: ["python3", "test.py"], 
  stdout: "piped",
  stderr: "piped"
});

const output = await cmd.output() // "piped" must be set
const outStr = new TextDecoder().decode(output);

const error = await cmd.stderrOutput();
const errorStr = new TextDecoder().decode(error);

cmd.close(); // Don't forget to close it

console.log(outStr, errorStr);
```

---

If you don't pass `stdout` property you'll get the output directly to `stdout`

```
 const p = Deno.run({
      cmd: ["python3", "test.py"]
 });

 await p.status();
 // output to stdout "Hello Deno"
 // calling p.output() will result in an Error
 p.close()
```

---

You can also send the output to a File

```
// --allow-run --allow-read --allow-write
const filepath = "/tmp/output";
const file = await Deno.open(filepath, {
      create: true,
      write: true
 });

const p = Deno.run({
      cmd: ["python3", "test.py"],
      stdout: file.rid,
      stderr: file.rid // you can use different file for stderr
});

await p.status();
p.close();
file.close();

const fileContents = await Deno.readFile(filepath);
const text = new TextDecoder().decode(fileContents);

console.log(text)
```

---

In order to check status code of the process you need to use `.status()`

```
const status = await cmd.status()
// { success: true, code: 0, signal: undefined }
// { success: false, code: number, signal: number }
```

---

In case you need to write data to `stdin` you can do it like this:

```
const p = Deno.run({
    cmd: ["python", "-c", "import sys; assert 'foo' == sys.stdin.read();"],
    stdin: "piped",
  });


// send other value for different status code
const msg = new TextEncoder().encode("foo"); 
const n = await p.stdin.write(msg);

p.stdin.close()

const status = await p.status();

p.close()
console.log(status)
```

---

You'll need to run Deno with: `--allow-run` flag in order to use `Deno.run`

Comment: you don't need to, unless you're reading a file like my second example.

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks for the amazing explanation!! I picked up quite a lot.