# How to spawn child process and communicate with it Deno?

Tags: deno

Suppose I have 2 script, father.ts and child.ts, how do I spawn child.ts from father.ts and periodically send message from father.ts to child.ts ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the [Worker API](https://deno.land/manual/runtime/workers)

**father.ts**

```
const worker = new Worker("./child.ts", { type: "module", deno: true });
worker.postMessage({ filename: "./log.txt" });
```

**child.ts**

```
self.onmessage = async (e) => {
  const { filename } = e.data;
  const text = await Deno.readTextFile(filename);
  console.log(text);
  self.close();
};
```

You can send messages using `.postMessage`

Comment: But child process in node allows you to run terminal commands. Seems like the does not

Comment: You can use Deno.run if you want to spawn shell commands.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61710787/how-to-run-a-python-script-from-deno see my answer there

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Am I able to send multiple commands and receive multiple responses for the same running process in Deno? I'm having a hard time finding examples.

Comment: In one of my examples I show how to write to `stdin`. You need to read from stdout and write to stdin.

Comment: why is it called 'worker'?

Comment: Because Deno tries to implement Web APIs when it makes sense, they didn't create the name https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker

Answer (score 0):

You can use child processes. Here is an example: [`proc` with `PushIterable`](https://deno.land/x/proc/examples/pushiterable/README.md)

This will let you send and receive multiple commands from non-Deno child processes asynchronously, as well as Deno child processes.

Be careful as this requires `--allow-run` to work, and this almost always breaks out of the sandbox, if you care about that.