# How can a child worker send message to parent process in Deno?

Tags: deno

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62085642/6587634), I know that a parent process can talk to a child worker, but how about the other way around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the worker you have to use [`Worker.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage)

```js
self.postMessage('hi')
```

And in the main process:

```js
const worker = new Worker("./worker.js", { type: "module", deno: true });

worker.addEventListener('message', message => {
    console.log('message', message);
    // message.data === 'hi'
});
```

Regarding [`self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self)

> The Window.self read-only property returns the window itself, as a
>   WindowProxy. It can be used with dot notation on a window object (that
>   is, window.self) or standalone (self). **The advantage of the standalone
>   notation is that a similar notation exists for non-window contexts,
>   such as in Web Workers**. By using self, you can refer to the global
>   scope in a way that will work not only in a window context (self will
>   resolve to window.self) **but also in a worker context** (self will then
>   resolve to WorkerGlobalScope.self).

Comment: Where comes the self variable?

Comment: From the worker, it's in the worker scope. You can see it in the link.

Comment: well it's a global object, in the browser you can do: `self === window`. In the worker `self` is the worker.

Comment: Thanks I found the reference here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self